# How to make only the first element of a array capitalize in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been given a string. First, I transform it into a array and then I try to capitalize only words into the condition. One of the conditions is that the first string is capitalized.
And it's just the one that is left

```
class Book
# write your code her
attr_reader :title
    def title=(new_title)
        words = new_title.split(" ")
        if words.length > 1     
            final_title = ""
            final_title = words.map! {|a| ((a != "and" && a != "the") && a.length > 2) ? a.capitalize : a}
            @title = final_title.join(" ") 
        else
            @title = new_title.capitalize
        end
    end
end
```

That's what I've done until now.

I tried to use `each_with_index` but `map!` doesn't work with it.

I expected:

```
"To Kill a Mockingbird"
```

but I got:

```
"to Kill a Mockingbird"
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure! Just a minute

Comment: Note: You don't need to initialize `final_title`.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework. If so you should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421

Comment: Thanks the Tin Man!
I've tried to solve it and I know how it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.9.3, Ruby has had [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).  The method `map` without a block returns an `Enumerator`, so you can do the following:

```
final_title = words.map.with_index do |word, i|
  if i != 0 && (word == "and" || word == "the" || word.length < 3)
    word.downcase
  else
    word.capitalize
  end
end
```

Clearly, you should make sure your title is lowercase to begin with, or the code checking for "and" and "the" won't work.

Comment: Edited to deal with case issues and get rid of unnecessary map!.

Comment: That's why I said you need to make sure your title is lower case to begin with.

Answer (score 8):

I'd start by separating the first word from the remaining words:

```
first, *rest = new_title.split(' ')
```

Then I would capitalize the first word:

```
first.capitalize!
```

Afterwards, I would capitalize each remaining word matching the conditions:

```
rest.select { |w| w != 'and' && w != 'the' && w.length > 2 }.each(&:capitalize!)
```

And finally put everything back together:

```
[first, *rest].join(' ')
```

Comment: You could first capitalize the first letter of the string before splitting it and doing the word-by-word processing. This way the first word will always be capitalized!

Comment: Let's see : You create too many objects, there's no need to separate first and rest. Your code only works if `newtitle` is lowercase, but you still get 8 upvotes. Do you have a marketing department working for you? :)

Comment: @EricDuminil I have no idea what's going on :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can map over an array with an index, but you have to do it like this:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(new_title)
    words = new_title.split
    final_title = words.map.with_index { |word, i| primary_word?(word) || i == 0 ? word.capitalize : word }
    @title = final_title.join(' ')
  end

  def primary_word?(word)
    ((word != 'and' && word != 'the') && word.length > 2)
  end
end
```

For clarity, I also extracted the logic for determining if a word should be capitalized into its own method.

Comment: Is the `else` part needed?

Comment: It's not desirable to use "edit" or "update" tags in questions or answers. See "[Should 'Edit:' in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/)"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much shorter version, using [`gsub` with block](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) :

- It works with  any case as input
- It checks directly in the regex if the word has at least 3 characters
- It uses capitalize on `new_title` : that way, the first word is capitalized and all the others are lowercase before the processing.

Here's the method :

```
OMIT_CAPITALIZE = %w(the and)
new_title.capitalize.gsub(/\S{3,}/) do |word|
  OMIT_CAPITALIZE.include?(word) ?  word : word.capitalize
end
```

Here's a way to integrate it into your class. `title` has been added as a parameter to `initialize` for easier use of `Book` :

```
class Book
  OMIT_CAPITALIZE = %w(the and)

  attr_reader :title

  def initialize(title)
    self.title = title
  end

  def title=(new_title)
    @title = new_title.capitalize.gsub(/\S{3,}/) do |word|
      OMIT_CAPITALIZE.include?(word) ?  word : word.capitalize
    end
  end
end

puts Book.new('to kill a mockingbird').title
# To Kill a Mockingbird
puts Book.new('ThE beauty and THE beast').title
# The Beauty and the Beast
puts Book.new('TO BE OR NOT TO BE').title
# To be or Not to be
```

Comment: Very good answer! 
Just didn't accept because it's an overkill. Also, the accepted question explained the doubt that I had.

Comment: @VictorFeitosa: Just curious, why do you think it's an overkill?

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't give all the context necessary:
I was running a exercise that needed me to write code until I passed.
Your two examples where not in the test so I just needed a line to make the first word capitalized. 
But your code is more general and simple than others

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```